# Loop iteration of an array string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop

I'm currently trying to solve a Title Capitalization problem. I have a method that takes in a sentence, splits it into words, compare the words with a check list of words.

Based on this check list, I lowercase the words if they are in the list. Uppercase any words not in the list. The first and last words are always capitalized.

Here is my method:

```
public string TitleCase(string title)
{
        LinkedList<string> wordsList = new LinkedList<string>();
        string[] listToCheck = { "a", "the", "to", "in", "with", "and", "but", "or" };
        string[] words = title.Split(null);
        var last = words.Length - 1;
        var firstWord = CapitalizeWord(words[0]);
        var lastWord = CapitalizeWord(words[last]);

        wordsList.AddFirst(firstWord);
        for (var i = 1; i <= last - 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (var s in listToCheck)
            {
                if (words[i].Equals(s))
                {
                    wordsList.AddLast(LowercaseWord(words[i]));
                }
                else
                {
                    wordsList.AddLast(CapitalizeWord(words[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        wordsList.AddLast(lastWord);
        var sentence = string.Join(" ", wordsList);
        return sentence;
    }
```

Running this with the example and expecting the result:

`var result = TitleCase("i love solving problems and it is fun");
Assert.AreEqual("I Love Solving Problems and It Is Fun", result);`

I get instead:

```
"I Love Love Love Love Love Love Love Love Solving Solving Solving Solving Solving Solving Solving Solving Problems Problems Problems Problems Problems Problems Problems Problems And And And And And and And And It It It It It It It It Is Is Is Is Is Is Is Is Fun"
```

If you look closely one `and` is lowercased. Any tips to how I solve this?

---

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `for`, then debug the code and press "F10" to step through it and see what's going on.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through your code. Keep a watch on how your wordsList is growing, and you will see what goes wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing some extra looping when you go through each of the words to check, and you're not exiting the loop as soon as you find a match (so you're adding the word on each check). To fix this issue in your specific code, you would do something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= last - 1; i++)
{
    bool foundMatch = false;

    foreach (var s in listToCheck)
    {
        if (words[i].Equals(s))
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundMatch)
    {
        wordsList.AddLast(LowercaseWord(words[i]));
    }
    else
    {
        wordsList.AddLast(CapitalizeWord(words[i]));
    }
}
```

However there is a much easier way, which other answers have provided. But I wanted to point out a couple of other things:

1. You are creating an unnecessary `LinkedList`. You already have a list of the words you can manipulate in the `words` array, so you'll save some memory by just using that.
2. I think there is a bug in your code (and in some of the answers) where if someone passes in a string with a capital `A` word in the middle, it will not be converted to lowercase because the `Equals` method (or in the case of other answers, the `Contains` method) does a case-sensitive comparison by default. So you might want to pass a case-insensitive comparer to that method.
3. You don't need to do separate checks for the first and last word. You can just have a single `if` statement with these checks in the body of your loop

So, here's what I would do:

```
public static string TitleCase(string title)
{
    var listToCheck = new[]{ "a", "the", "to", "in", "with", "and", "but", "or" };
    var words = title.Split(null);

    // Loop through all words in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        // If we're on the first or last index, or if 
        // the word is not in our list, Capitalize it
        if (i == 0 || i == (words.Length - 1) || 
            !listToCheck.Contains(words[i], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            words[i] = CapitalizeWord(words[i]); 
        }
        else
        {
            words[i] = LowercaseWord(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return string.Join(" ", words);
}
```

Comment: Indeed. I tried with `var result = TitleCase("wHy DoeS A biRd Fly?");
            Assert.AreEqual("Why Does a Bird Fly?", result);` and had issues with "A". The above code fixed that issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the foreach loop, you are doing eight checks (the length of the listToCheck array)  for each word - and adding the word to the list each time. I'd also recommend using a Linq query, so it should look like this:

```
        for (var i = 1; i <= last - 1; i++) {

            if(listToCheck.Contains(words[i]))
                wordsList.AddLast(LowercaseWord(words[i]));
            else 
                wordsList.AddLast(CapitalizeWord(words[i]));
        }
```

Also, the reason the sixth 'and' is lowercased is because it is the sixth word in the listToCheck array. On the sixth time around the foreach loop, it succeeds the test and is written in lower case, all the others fail so it is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop within a loop which messes things up, simplify the code to have just one loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= last - 1; i++)
{
    // No inner loop
    // Use the .Contains() method to see if it's a key word
    if (listToCheck.Contains(words[i]))
    {
        wordsList.AddLast(LowercaseWord(words[i]));
    }
    else
    {
        wordsList.AddLast(CapitalizeWord(words[i]));
    }
}
```

Output:

> I Love Solving Problems and It Is Fun

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers the loop within the loop doesn't exit.
Just a suggestion, with Linq you could combine checking for the first and last word (through index) and check the `ListToCheck` together:

```
public string TitleCase(string title)
{        
    string[] listToCheck = { "a", "the", "to", "in", "with", "and", "but", "or" };
    string[] words = title.Split(null);
    var last = words.Length - 1;
    return string.Join(" ", words.Select(w=>w.ToLower()).Select(((w,i) => i == 0 || i == last || !listToCheck.Contains(w) ? CapitalizeWord(w) : w)));
}
```

Note, in this solution the first `Select` makes sure all words are in lowercase, so the lookup in `listToCheck` can be done without special comparisons. Because the words are already in lowercase, that doesn't have to be done any more if the word doesn't have to be capitalized.